# Get actual path from path with wildcard

Tags: powershell, if-statement

When using `Test-Path` in an `if` statement, I am looking to get the path that the if statement succeeds with.

For example, these files exist in C:

```
C:\Test6_1_15.txt
C:\Test6_2_15.txt
C:\Test6_3_15.txt
C:\Test6_4_15.txt
```

what do I do in the "then" branch?

```psh
$Path = "C:\Test6_*_15.txt"
if (Test-Path $Path)
{
   # if test passes because there are 4 files that fit the test, but I want to be
   # able to output the file that made the if statement succeed. 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`Resolve-Path`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849858(v=wps.620).aspx):

```
if(($Paths = @(Resolve-Path "C:\Test6_*_15.txt"))){
    foreach($file in $Paths){
        # do stuff
    }
} else {
    # Resolve-Path was unable to resolve "C:\Test6_*_15.txt" to anything
}
```

Comment: oooo yes... always forget about that one.

Comment: I'd do `if (Test-Path $Path) { $paths = Resolve-Path $Path; ... }`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `get-item $path`, that will return actual file name(s) in its result.

Answer (score 2):

You will not get that with `Test-Path`. `Test-Path` returns a boolean value(s) representing the presence of the path(s) passed. Looking at the description from [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx)

> It returns TRUE ($true) if all elements exist and FALSE ($false) if any are missing

If you just want the actual filenames that match then use `Get-Item` as it supports standard wildcards. You can get information from the `System.IO.FileInfo` objects that `Get-Item` returns.

Comment: However, if `Test-Path $path` is true, `get-item $path` is guaranteed to return at least 1 entry, so using both is probably better in terms of error handling.

Comment: Of course yes. I was not trying to suggest one over the other. Checking the return value of `Get-Item` would work just as well in that scenario